# ng-show if html element exists in current template angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-template

I have a help button which I want to show in the layout only if there is a specific div #helpId in the template. (when clicked will display #helpId in a modal window).

Is this possible without setting a variable in every controller?

Thank you!

Comment: The help button is outside the template while the `div #helpId` is inside the template - am I correct in my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I miss the point but if you use ng-show you have to provide some function to detect the wanted div #helpid anyway. This function could contain some jQuery code to find the element.

But I would suggest to implement a little service holding the state of your app. Something like that (you can extend this approach):

```
myapp.service('Context', function () {
    var context = {}; // current status
    return {
        get: function () { 
            return context;
        },
        set: function (state) { 
            context.state = state;
            return context;
        }
    };
};
```

You can use a $rootScope variable instead (as you already suggested) but polluting the $rootScope isn't such a good idea.